# multiple line UILabel is truncating

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilabel

I want to display status on a UILabel.  I want it to wraparound at word breaks if it's too long, and I want font size to shrink if not enough room in the UILabel.

UILabel is created in storyboard, and its Lines = 2, and Autoshrink is Minimum font Scale 0.5

But I can't make this happen.  Text keeps truncating.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:
In storyboard:
1. stretched UILabel vertically bigger
2. Lines=0
3. Line Break = word Wrap
4. Autoshurink = Fixed Font Size